# Pervasive 8 and Python

Tags: python, database, pervasive

Is it possible to access a Pervasive 8 (not Pervasive SQL) database from python?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Pervasive, but from a quick web search it looks like people are using some kind of ODBC driver to access Pervasive 8.

ODBC databases can be used from python in Windows using PyODBC: http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/

Comment: pyodbc is cross-platform. It is the Pervasive 8 driver that seems to be windows-only, not pyodbc.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can. here is the working code

```
import os
import sys
import pyodbc

def main():
   conn_str = 'Driver={Pervasive ODBC Interface};server=localhost;DBQ=DATABASENAME'
   db = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
   c = db.cursor()
   c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME")
   row = c.fetchone()
   if row:
      print(row)
   return 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
   sys.exit(main())
```